# Angular 2 plugin for Abobe Brackets

Tags: angular

Is there a plugin released for Angular 2 syntax and auto completion in Adobe Brackets. There are plugins available for Angularjs 1.x but I couldn't find one for Angular 2

Answer (score -1):

Seems, theres no angular2 plugin available as of now. But you can add latest TypeScript support to Brackets.